# Change style of chapters using KOMA-Script

Tags: chapters, koma-script

I would like to change the chapter style so that chapters start at the top of the page.
With

```
\renewcommand\chapter{\@startsection{chapter}{0}{\z@}%
{-2em}%
{6pt}%
{\LARGE\bfseries}}
```

this works fine for numbered chapters. How can I do this for unnumbered chapters such as TOC, LOF etc?

Comment: Have a look at `chapterheadstartvskip`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Thank you for the answers! Unfortunately {chapterheadstartvskip} works only for regular chapters, not for TOC and LOF.
I am sorry for not having provided a minimal example. I am using scrreprt and try to avoid using the titlesec package since it produces a warning when used with KOMA-Script classes.

Comment: How are you using TOC and LOF? Cause it works in my example: `\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{-2\topskip}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\blinddocument
\end{document}
`

Comment: I tried to produce a MWE and found out that it's the tocloft package that is producing the additional space for TOC and LOF titles.

Comment: `tocloft` is also not recommended when using a KOMA class.

Comment: Ok, I see. Will have to remove it and find some workarounds. Thank you again!